# How to install the latest build of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

On Dec. 18, Radim Blazek developed the '*Improved raster singleband pseudocolor classification GUI*'. Being new at QGIS, I have no idea how to go about updating to this version.

Could someone possibly assist me with this?

Comment: Where did you see this message?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 10):

I guess you are talking about this change [9fce669ba](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/9fce669ba20529ce9822268268cb0e5b4cf73300). This change is in the current dev build of QGIS.  In order to use this new feature you will have to install the latest dev build.

Each platform has its own way of getting the current dev build.

- On Windows you should use the [OSGeo4W installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/). Use the advanced install option and select `qgis-dev` from the desktop section.
- On OS X you can use the builds at http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/
- For linux you will need to use the package manager for your selected platform.